# Матрица с координатами

Tags: html, jquery, json, веб-программирование, матрицы

С матрицами я раньше не работал . Но для дела нужно в ней разобраться . Знающие камрады подскажите . Проблема в том , что я не могу понять как расшифровываться координаты в этой матрице. Если это положение по  x и y то почему там нереальные координаты а 0 и 1 . Мне нужно матрицу создать с координатами по x,y - которая отображает положение svg файлов.
   Код брас с библиотеки для поиска пути: Pathfinding.js

```
Вот пример кода:

 function drawPath(path) {
   setTimeout(function loop() {
       var current = path.shift();
        // не понимаю эту часть 
       var point = document.querySelector('.c'+current[1]+current[0])
       point.classList.add('path')

       if (path.length)
           setTimeout(loop, 500);
    }, 500);
}

window.onload = function () {
    // add eventListener for tizenhwkey
    document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
        if(e.keyName == "back")
            tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
    });
// эту 
    var matrix = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    var grid = new PF.Grid(5, 5, matrix);

    var finder = new PF.AStarFinder();


     // и эту
    var path = finder.findPath(0, 0, 2, 3, grid);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(path));

    drawPath(path);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Что за библиотека не знаю, но по всей видимости `findPath` возвращает путь в виде массива пар координат. Пары это просто массивы длины 2. Т.е. `path` имеет вид `[[0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0, 3], [1, 3], [2, 3]]`. Далее в функции `drawPath` из `path` на каждом шаге извлекается следующая точка ([Array.prototype.shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)), поэтому `current` это просто пара координат `[x, y]` текущей точки в пути.